# Return last inserted objectId with Xamarin and Parse.com

Tags: c#, parse-platform, xamarin

I am new to C# so please be gentle with me.

How do I get the objectId of an inserted object with Xamarin and Parse.com

```
var obj = new ParseObject ("TestObject");
obj ["foo"] = "Hello, world!  This is a Xamarin app using Parse!";
await obj.SaveAsync();

//Success -> here I want to get the objectId of the freshly inserted objectId
//Error -> do something on error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `objectId` property of `obj` should be populated as soon as the save completes.

Comment: It worked Console.WriteLine(obj.ObjectId); Thank you.